# Java 7 update 25 Crash

Tags: java, jvm-crash

My app is getting crashed silently. It doesn't log anything so I have put vm arg for error file.

App is dong image processing downloading, resizing and writing and at a time 30 thread are active with per thread couple of db calls. Stack Trace is for reference

```
## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xf77ae268, pid=29935, tid=4093590416
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b15
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5f2268]  ParRootScanWithBarrierTwoGensClosure::do_oop(oopDesc**)+0x38
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x08a65c00):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00000000,0x00000000] [id=29937]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x57538884

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x8b2bc154, ECX=0x57538880, EDX=0x57538878
ESP=0xf3ff2bc0, EBP=0xf3ff2bd8, ESI=0x76576560, EDI=0x1e8ea24c
EIP=0xf77ae268, EFLAGS=0x00010293, CR2=0x57538884

Top of Stack: (sp=0xf3ff2bc0)
0xf3ff2bc0:   f3ff2ccc fffffffe f3ff2c08 8b2bc154
0xf3ff2bd0:   8b2bc158 f1a3b2b8 f3ff2c08 f75959d8
0xf3ff2be0:   64200108 8b2bc154 f3ff2c34 f3ff2c34
0xf3ff2bf0:   65c00010 80343000 f1a3b2c0 f1a3b158
0xf3ff2c00:   8b2bc148 f3ff2ccc f3ff2c48 f745124a
0xf3ff2c10:   f1a3b158 8b2bc148 f3ff2ccc f3ff2c34
0xf3ff2c20:   f794f368 08a5feb4 fffffff8 f79ad110
0xf3ff2c30:   00000005 8b2bc000 00000080 8b2bc200 

Instructions: (pc=0xf77ae268)
0xf77ae248:   08 39 72 24 0f 86 8e 00 00 00 8b 3e 8b 56 04 89
0xf77ae258:   f8 83 e0 03 83 f8 03 0f 84 ab 00 00 00 8d 4a 08
0xf77ae268:   8b 59 04 83 fb 00 0f 8e c4 00 00 00 f6 c3 01 75
0xf77ae278:   6f 89 d8 c1 f8 02 8b 5d 08 80 3d 34 df 9c f7 00 

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x8b2bc154 is an oop
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$NotifyHandshakeThread$1 
 - klass: 'sun/security/ssl/SSLSocketImpl$NotifyHandshakeThread$1'
ECX=0x57538880 is an unknown value
EDX=0x57538878 is an unknown value
ESP=0xf3ff2bc0 is an unknown value
EBP=0xf3ff2bd8 is an unknown value
ESI=0x76576560 is an oop
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 4096
EDI=0x1e8ea24c is an unknown value

Stack: [0x00000000,0x00000000],  sp=0xf3ff2bc0,  free space=3997642k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x5f2268]  ParRootScanWithBarrierTwoGensClosure::do_oop(oopDesc**)+0x38
V  [libjvm.so+0x3d99d8]  instanceKlass::oop_oop_iterate_nv_m(oopDesc*, FilteringClosure*, MemRegion)+0x98
V  [libjvm.so+0x29524a]  FreeListSpace_DCTOC::walk_mem_region_with_cl_par(MemRegion, HeapWord*, HeapWord*, FilteringClosure*)+0x11a
V  [libjvm.so+0x2954bb]  FreeListSpace_DCTOC::walk_mem_region_with_cl(MemRegion, HeapWord*, HeapWord*, FilteringClosure*)+0x6b
V  [libjvm.so+0x672795]  Filtering_DCTOC::walk_mem_region(MemRegion, HeapWord*, HeapWord*)+0x55
V  [libjvm.so+0x6726b5]  DirtyCardToOopClosure::do_MemRegion(MemRegion)+0xe5
V  [libjvm.so+0x22a758]  ClearNoncleanCardWrapper::do_MemRegion(MemRegion)+0x108
V  [libjvm.so+0x5ebb51]  CardTableModRefBS::process_stride(Space*, MemRegion, int, int, OopsInGenClosure*, CardTableRS*, signed char**, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x101
V  [libjvm.so+0x5ebc42]  CardTableModRefBS::non_clean_card_iterate_parallel_work(Space*, MemRegion, OopsInGenClosure*, CardTableRS*, int)+0x92
V  [libjvm.so+0x228fe2]  CardTableModRefBS::non_clean_card_iterate_possibly_parallel(Space*, MemRegion, OopsInGenClosure*, CardTableRS*)+0x42
V  [libjvm.so+0x22a5c7]  CardTableRS::younger_refs_in_space_iterate(Space*, OopsInGenClosure*)+0x37
V  [libjvm.so+0x2c29bc]  ConcurrentMarkSweepGeneration::younger_refs_iterate(OopsInGenClosure*)+0x2c
V  [libjvm.so+0x399185]  GenCollectedHeap::gen_process_strong_roots(int, bool, bool, bool, SharedHeap::ScanningOption, OopsInGenClosure*, bool, OopsInGenClosure*)+0x95
V  [libjvm.so+0x5eebf7]  ParNewGenTask::work(unsigned int)+0xa7
V  [libjvm.so+0x7350b9]  GangWorker::loop()+0xe9
V  [libjvm.so+0x734c48]  GangWorker::run()+0x18
V  [libjvm.so+0x5dc401]  java_start(Thread*)+0x111
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x5912]  start_thread+0xe2
---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x64388400 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20984, stack(0x67b5e000,0x67baf000)]
  0x656db000 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20983, stack(0x67e88000,0x67ed9000)]
  0x08ccc800 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20982, stack(0x67abc000,0x67b0d000)]
  0x65a04800 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20981, stack(0x67b0d000,0x67b5e000)]
  0x66223400 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20980, stack(0x67d95000,0x67de6000)]
  0x664c4c00 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20979, stack(0x67a6b000,0x67abc000)]
  0x666ba800 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20978, stack(0x67c51000,0x67ca2000)]
  0x093e6400 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20977, stack(0x67cf3000,0x67d44000)]
  0x0912f400 JavaThread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=20976, stack(0x67d44000,0x67d95000)]
  0x6661ac00 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20941, stack(0x681a7000,0x681f8000)]
  0x69b00400 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31006, stack(0x67e37000,0x67e88000)]
  0x093ed000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30929, stack(0x68156000,0x681a7000)]
  0x08fafc00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30875, stack(0x685c6000,0x68617000)]
  0x09055000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30821, stack(0x67fcc000,0x6801d000)]
  0x08e95000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30740, stack(0x68431000,0x68482000)]
  0x08ec1800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30737, stack(0x687ac000,0x687fd000)]
  0x08cd6c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30695, stack(0x68063000,0x680b4000)]
  0x08d74000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30640, stack(0x67f7b000,0x67fcc000)]
  0x08c46000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30597, stack(0x683e0000,0x68431000)]
  0x08c9b000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30547, stack(0x68105000,0x68156000)]
  0x092c1c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30546, stack(0x68249000,0x6829a000)]
  0x093b3c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30496, stack(0x6838f000,0x683e0000)]
  0x09259400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30445, stack(0x6829a000,0x682eb000)]
  0x08fa3800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30398, stack(0x68668000,0x686b9000)]
  0x09056c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30360, stack(0x6833e000,0x6838f000)]
  0x08d19800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30359, stack(0x684d3000,0x68524000)]
  0x08ee4400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30317, stack(0x68524000,0x68575000)]
  0x08d19000 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30259, stack(0x68617000,0x68668000)]
  0x093d3c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30187, stack(0x68482000,0x684d3000)]
  0x092c2c00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30129, stack(0x68575000,0x685c6000)]
  0x08c45800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30128, stack(0x686b9000,0x6870a000)]
  0x09465c00 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30093, stack(0x6875b000,0x687ac000)]
  0x091e9400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30062, stack(0x687fd000,0x6884e000)]
  0x091bcc00 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30054, stack(0x68a46000,0x68a97000)]
  0x69b5a400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-30" [_thread_in_native, id=30052, stack(0x68a97000,0x68ae8000)]
  0x69b58c00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-29" [_thread_blocked, id=30051, stack(0x68ae8000,0x68b39000)]
  0x69b82c00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-28" [_thread_blocked, id=30050, stack(0x68b39000,0x68b8a000)]
  0x69b81400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-27" [_thread_blocked, id=30049, stack(0x68b8a000,0x68bdb000)]
  0x697ca400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-26" [_thread_blocked, id=30048, stack(0x68bdb000,0x68c2c000)]
  0x69897800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-25" [_thread_blocked, id=30047, stack(0x68c2c000,0x68c7d000)]
  0x697cc000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-24" [_thread_blocked, id=30046, stack(0x68c7d000,0x68cce000)]
  0x697cb400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-23" [_thread_blocked, id=30045, stack(0x68cce000,0x68d1f000)]
  0x6a0eb400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-22" [_thread_blocked, id=30044, stack(0x68e9f000,0x68ef0000)]
  0x69cb7800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-21" [_thread_blocked, id=30043, stack(0x68ef0000,0x68f41000)]
  0x6a2dd800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-20" [_thread_blocked, id=30042, stack(0x68f41000,0x68f92000)]
  0x6a2df400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=30041, stack(0x68f92000,0x68fe3000)]
  0x6a2dc000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=30040, stack(0x68fe3000,0x69034000)]
  0x6a2da800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-17" [_thread_blocked, id=30039, stack(0x69034000,0x69085000)]
  0x6a2d9000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-16" [_thread_blocked, id=30038, stack(0x69085000,0x690d6000)]
  0x69c80400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=30037, stack(0x690d6000,0x69127000)]
  0x69c7ec00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=30036, stack(0x69127000,0x69178000)]
  0x69c7d400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=30035, stack(0x69178000,0x691c9000)]
  0x69c7bc00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=30034, stack(0x691c9000,0x6921a000)]
  0x69c7a000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=30033, stack(0x6921a000,0x6926b000)]
  0x69c0ec00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=30032, stack(0x6926b000,0x692bc000)]
  0x69c0d400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=30031, stack(0x692bc000,0x6930d000)]
  0x69c0bc00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=30030, stack(0x6930d000,0x6935e000)]
  0x69c0a400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=30029, stack(0x6935e000,0x693af000)]
  0x69869400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=30028, stack(0x693af000,0x69400000)]
  0x69868400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=30027, stack(0x6950d000,0x6955e000)]
  0x69867400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=30026, stack(0x6955e000,0x695af000)]
  0x69eda000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=30025, stack(0x695af000,0x69600000)]
  0x69ed9000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=30024, stack(0x6991e000,0x6996f000)]
  0x69ed8000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=30023, stack(0x6996f000,0x699c0000)]
  0x09009800 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30022, stack(0x69f0d000,0x69f5e000)]
  0x0936cc00 JavaThread "AggregationEngine.AggregationThread.CallDataAggregationEngine" [_thread_blocked, id=29993, stack(0x69f5e000,0x69faf000)]
  0x0936b800 JavaThread "AggregationEngine.AggregationProcessorThread.CallDataAggregationEngine" [_thread_blocked, id=29992, stack(0x6a10d000,0x6a15e000)]
  0x09375000 JavaThread "SUT IdleConnReaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29991, stack(0x6a15e000,0x6a1af000)]
  0x09066400 JavaThread "UCP-worker-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29990, stack(0x69faf000,0x6a000000)]
  0x6a033800 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29985, stack(0x6a325000,0x6a376000)]
  0x6a027c00 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29984, stack(0x6a1af000,0x6a200000)]
  0x6a25c000 JavaThread "AggregationEngine.AggregationThread.DatabaseStats" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29955, stack(0x6a54c000,0x6a59d000)]
  0x6a259400 JavaThread "AggregationEngine.AggregationProcessorThread.DatabaseStats" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29954, stack(0x6a59d000,0x6a5ee000)]
  0x6a225800 JavaThread "OverrideWatcherService" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29953, stack(0x6a376000,0x6a3c7000)]
  0x08bc1400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29947, stack(0x6acae000,0x6acff000)]
  0x08bbf800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29946, stack(0x6acff000,0x6ad80000)]
  0x08bb5000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29945, stack(0x6ad80000,0x6ae01000)]
  0x08bb3800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29944, stack(0x6ae01000,0x6ae52000)]
  0x08bb1c00 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29943, stack(0x6ae52000,0x6aea3000)]
  0x08b76000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29942, stack(0x6b0a3000,0x6b0f4000)]
  0x08b71000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29941, stack(0x6b0f4000,0x6b145000)]
  0x08a5ec00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=29936, stack(0xf7142000,0xf7193000)]

Other Threads:
  0x08b6b400 VMThread [stack: 0x6b145000,0x6b1c6000] [id=29940]
  0x08bc3400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x6ac2d000,0x6acae000] [id=29948]

=>0x08a65c00 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00000000,0x00000000] [id=29937]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x08a5d9d8] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x08b6b400
[0x08a5de50] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x6a2df400

Heap
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 383181K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)

Card table byte_map: [0x6facf000,0x6fef0000] byte_map_base: 0x6f74f880

Polling page: 0xf7f7c000

Code Cache  [0xf40b4000, 0xf4784000, 0xf70b4000)
 total_blobs=2481 nmethods=2308 adapters=124 free_code_cache=42271Kb largest_free_block=43193792

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 72541.712 Thread 0x08bbf800 nmethod 2490 0xf46da488 code [0xf46da560, 0xf46da5b0]
Event: 72561.996 Thread 0x08bbf800 2491   !         javax.crypto.Cipher::chooseFirstProvider (298 bytes)
Event: 72566.161 Thread 0x08bbf800 nmethod 2491 0xf46da2c8 code [0xf46da3c0, 0xf46da410]
Event: 72578.585 Thread 0x08bb5000 nmethod 2489 0xf4776b48 code [0xf4777320, 0xf477bf74]
Event: 73144.091 Thread 0x08bbf800 2492             java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl::getTimeout (5 bytes)
Event: 73146.474 Thread 0x08bbf800 nmethod 2492 0xf46da148 code [0xf46da220, 0xf46da270]
Event: 73158.777 Thread 0x08bb5000 2493             java.net.SocketInputStream::read (15 bytes)
Event: 73162.489 Thread 0x08bb5000 nmethod 2493 0xf4747c08 code [0xf4747d00, 0xf4747d7c]
Event: 73466.447 Thread 0x08bbf800 2494             sun.security.ssl.MAC::seqNumIsHuge (40 bytes)
Event: 73467.893 Thread 0x08bbf800 nmethod 2494 0xf47479c8 code [0xf4747ac0, 0xf4747b70]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 76347.670 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=18124 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x6fef0000, 0x6fef0000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x77230000, 0x77230000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 330269K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
}
Event: 76352.324 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18124 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x77230000, 0x77230000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 330269K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
Event: 76353.913 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=18125 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x6fef0000, 0x6fef0000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x76570000, 0x76570000, 0x77230000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 340191K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
}
Event: 76358.105 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18125 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x76570000, 0x76570000, 0x77230000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 340191K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
Event: 76359.476 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=18126 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x6fef0000, 0x6fef0000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x77230000, 0x77230000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 347427K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
}
Event: 76363.741 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18126 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x77230000, 0x77230000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 347427K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
Event: 76366.446 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=18127 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x6fef0000, 0x6fef0000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x76570000, 0x76570000, 0x77230000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 366853K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
}
Event: 76370.687 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18127 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x76570000, 0x76570000, 0x77230000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 366853K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
Event: 76372.371 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=18128 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x6fef0000, 0x6fef0000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x77230000, 0x77230000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 377879K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)
}
Event: 76376.742 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18128 (full 650):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x77230000, 0x77230000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 377879K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe000, 0xf3ef0000)

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 9954.590 Thread 0x69b58c00 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0xf436b9fc
Event: 10104.257 Thread 0x69c7d400 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0xf46db26c
Event: 10136.026 Thread 0x69c0a400 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0xf46c63b4
Event: 17339.271 Thread 0x69ed8000 Uncommon trap 114 fr.pc 0xf43c53e8
Event: 17340.839 Thread 0x69ed8000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0xf466df30
Event: 26815.259 Thread 0x69b58c00 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0xf466df30
Event: 31367.653 Thread 0x69897800 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0xf466df30
Event: 41217.522 Thread 0x69b5a400 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0xf466df30
Event: 70657.311 Thread 0x093b3c00 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0xf4212dc0
Event: 71982.244 Thread 0x69b58c00 Uncommon trap 184 fr.pc 0xf4557f2c

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 76119.547 Thread 0x69867400 Threw 0x6ffa5ea0 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:742
Event: 76124.215 Thread 0x69867400 Threw 0x7126d828 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:742
Event: 76128.125 Thread 0x6a2d9000 Threw 0x73796378 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:716
Event: 76128.125 Thread 0x6a2d9000 Threw 0x73796990 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:716
Event: 76130.630 Thread 0x69b82c00 Threw 0x702f49c8 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:716
Event: 76152.264 Thread 0x69867400 Threw 0x7058d8c8 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:742
Event: 76164.180 Thread 0x6a2dc000 Threw 0x719be298 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:716
Event: 76164.180 Thread 0x6a2dc000 Threw 0x719be8b0 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:716
Event: 76166.799 Thread 0x69867400 Threw 0x7554a910 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:742
Event: 76198.635 Thread 0x69868400 Threw 0x732445a8 at /HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u25-2-build-linux-i586-product/jdk7u25/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:716

Events (10 events):
Event: 76375.392 Thread 0x666ba800 Thread added: 0x666ba800
Event: 76375.866 Thread 0x664c4c00 Thread added: 0x664c4c00
Event: 76376.023 Thread 0x66223400 Thread added: 0x66223400
Event: 76376.082 Thread 0x65a04800 Thread added: 0x65a04800
Event: 76376.221 Thread 0x08ccc800 Thread added: 0x08ccc800
Event: 76376.637 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 76376.735 Thread 0x656db000 Thread added: 0x656db000
Event: 76376.735 Thread 0x64388400 Thread added: 0x64388400
Event: 76376.736 Thread 0x08c1f000 Thread exited: 0x08c1f000
Event: 76376.736 Thread 0x64b9ac00 Thread exited: 0x64b9ac00

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:ErrorFile=/opt/App/logs/ -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
java_command: ImageProcessorLauncher
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/hemanthchellangi/bin
USERNAME=root
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x71d560], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x71d560], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x5d74f0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x5d74f0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x5d74f0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x5d74f0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x5d6dd0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5d93c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x5d93c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5d93c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5d93c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:      2058744 kB
MemFree:         11256 kB
Buffers:           840 kB
Cached:          92664 kB
SwapCached:     511252 kB
Active:        1099720 kB
Inactive:       891532 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:      2058744 kB
LowFree:         11256 kB
SwapTotal:     1572856 kB
SwapFree:       607388 kB
Dirty:             620 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     1612648 kB
Mapped:           9796 kB
Slab:            31056 kB
PageTables:       8112 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   2602228 kB
Committed_AS:  2494060 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      1104 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359737207 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB


CPU:total 2 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, tsc

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)
stepping    : 1
cpu MHz     : 2199.998
cache size  : 4096 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx lm constant_tsc pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 4399.43
clflush size    : 64`enter code here`
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

Memory: 4k page, physical 2058744k(11256k free), swap 1572856k(607388k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.25-b01) for linux-x86 JRE (1.7.0_25-b15), built on Jun  5 2013 20:53:39 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ran out heap space.

```
Heap
  par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
```

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is that the GC has crashed.

The most likely cause is that something else (e.g. some native code library) has corrupted some heap objects, and that the GC has been tripped up by the corruption.

So what can you do?

Well the first thing I would try would be to upgrade to the latest patch of Java 7 and see it the problem recurs.  Java 7u25 is rather old, and if the problem is caused by some bug in the JVM or the standard libraries, there is a good chance that it has already been fixed.

If that fails, take a look at any native code libraries you wrote yourself:

- Are you doing things that could corrupt the heap?
- Are the libraries thread-safe?

Then look at the native libraries you may have included as part of 3rd-party libraries you are using.

- Do they claim to be thread-safe?
- Are there reports of related JVM crashes?

---

I would not blame this on a full heap.

```
Heap
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 118016K [0x6fef0000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x6fef0000, 0x76570000, 0x76570000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x76570000, 0x77230000, 0x77230000)
  to   space 13056K, 100% used [0x77230000, 0x77ef0000, 0x77ef0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1966080K, used 383181K [0x77ef0000, 0xefef0000, 0xefef0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 51256K, used 29682K [0xefef0000, 0xf30fe0
```

The "new" generation is full, but there is lots of space in the "concurrent mark-sweep" generation.  What was happening was that the collector was starting to collect the "new" generation when it ran into the heap corruption that crashed it.  (There are various clues in the native stack trace at the beginning of the dump.)

Comment: I'm using ImageIO libraries for image reading and writing JPEG images. Do you think that can be issue ? I use ImageIo.read  from url and then Image writer to write high quality JPEG images by creating IIOImage.

Comment: I would guess that that is part of the problem.  (Google "imagio native crash" ...)

Comment: yup imagiio is too much buggy..do you have any idea about reading images other then imageio as there is no open source library yet , apache imaging is still in snapshot..:(

Comment: I suspect that you are less likely to have problems if you do your image processing in a single thread.  Or maybe use an external command to do it.